# Returning value from list within a dict

Tags: python

Attempting to return a specific value of a key that's in a list within a dict.  I've tried iterating over items, searching specific ID's and not quite getting the result I'm after.

```
{
  'activeAccount': True,
  'country': 'USA',
  'state': 'CA',
  'users': [
    {
      'id': 'A',
      'firstName': 'Tom',
      'lastName': 'Cruise',
      'creditScore': '713',
      'balance': '65897.22',
      'debts': '12414.12',
      'savings': '15231.23'
    },
    {
      'id': 'B',
      'firstName': 'Jon',
      'lastName': 'Snow',
      'creditScore': '648',
      'balance': '12366.23',
      'debts': '522',
      'savings': '121588'
    },
    {
      'id': 'C',
      'firstName': 'Rick',
      'lastName': 'Sanchez',
      'creditScore': '655',
      'balance': '556425.33',
      'debts': '0',
      'savings': '125122.23'
    },
    {
      'id': 'D',
      'firstName': 'Monty',
      'lastName': 'Python',
      'creditScore': '815',
      'balance': '4512699.13',
      'debts': '4.25',
      'savings': '5499865.12'
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I retrieve a specific value of, for example, the credit score of `users[2]` to return the value?

```
655
```

I've tried the solution of `cScore = (dict['users'][2]['creditScore'])`, but this isn't ideal in situations of the objects changing order, etc.

Comment: Why assign a unique ID and then not use that ID as a key? The most sensical data structure (IMO) would be a dictionary in which keys are unique user IDs and the values should be a dictionary of key/value pairs of information that is pertinent to the user. That way, you never have to worry about list indices, and you can retrieve the info you want with `users[C][creditScore]`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to find the credit score of the third user in the list, `users[2]`, _or_ the user with an `id` j=key equal to `2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary value of `'users'` is a list. So you have to iterate through the list and search for the specific id.

Here's how you can do it.

```
for i in cust['users']:
    if i['id'] == '2':
        print (i['creditScore'])
```

I searched for `'id' == 'D'`. The output was `815`

The dictionary is defined as :

```
cust = {
  'activeAccount': True,
  'country': 'USA',
  'state': 'CA',
  'users': [
    {
      'id': 'A',
      'firstName': 'Tom',
      'lastName': 'Cruise',
      'creditScore': '713',
      'balance': '65897.22',
      'debts': '12414.12',
      'savings': '15231.23'
    },
    {
      'id': 'B',
      'firstName': 'Jon',
      'lastName': 'Snow',
      'creditScore': '648',
      'balance': '12366.23',
      'debts': '522',
      'savings': '121588'
    },
    {
      'id': 'C',
      'firstName': 'Rick',
      'lastName': 'Sanchez',
      'creditScore': '655',
      'balance': '556425.33',
      'debts': '0',
      'savings': '125122.23'
    },
    {
      'id': 'D',
      'firstName': 'Monty',
      'lastName': 'Python',
      'creditScore': '815',
      'balance': '4512699.13',
      'debts': '4.25',
      'savings': '5499865.12'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate through the list of dicts, looking for one with an id of 2.  Then you return the credit score from that dict.  Use this starter code:

```
for account in data_base:
    if account['id'] == 2:
        score = account['creditScore']
        break
```

Your underlying problem is that you chose a data representation that doesn't match your data access needs.  If you always reference your accounts by `id`, then change your list to a dict, keyed by that value.  If you look up accounts through various means, then you need to investigate some data base format that suits your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the user by ID within of a list of users you can use a `filter` function:

```
dict = {
  'activeAccount': True,
  'country': 'USA',
  'state': 'CA',
  'users': [
    {
      'id': 'A',
      'firstName': 'Tom',
      'lastName': 'Cruise',
      'creditScore': '713',
      'balance': '65897.22',
      'debts': '12414.12',
      'savings': '15231.23'
    },
    {
      'id': 'B',
      'firstName': 'Jon',
      'lastName': 'Snow',
      'creditScore': '648',
      'balance': '12366.23',
      'debts': '522',
      'savings': '121588'
    },
    {
      'id': 'C',
      'firstName': 'Rick',
      'lastName': 'Sanchez',
      'creditScore': '655',
      'balance': '556425.33',
      'debts': '0',
      'savings': '125122.23'
    },
    {
      'id': 'D',
      'firstName': 'Monty',
      'lastName': 'Python',
      'creditScore': '815',
      'balance': '4512699.13',
      'debts': '4.25',
      'savings': '5499865.12'
    }
  ]
}

# get the user with ID:"D"
user = list(filter(lambda u: u["id"] == "D", dict["users"]))[0]

# get the value
cScore = user["creditScore"]    # <-- Output: 815
```

#### Description

`lambda u: u["id"] == "D"` means: return True if the property "id" of a given element is "D".

It could be rewritten as a plain function:

```
def check_D(user):
    return user["id"] == "D"

user = list(filter(check_D, dict["users"]))[0]
```

`filter( <condition> , dict["users"])` means: to iterate through the list `dict["users"]` and to return all elements that meet the condition (the "lambda" in this case, or it could be any function that return True or False).

`user = list( ... )[0]` since a filter function returns an object, it's need to convert the object into a list and to get a first element of the list.

#### Another option

You can built a list comprehension with a condition (id == "D") and take a first element of the list:

```
creditScore = [usr["creditScore"] for usr in dict["users"] if usr["id"] == "D"][0]

print(creditScore) # <-- Output: 815
```